# R memory loop leakage

Tags: r, memory-leaks

R crashes when I loop. Let's say I need to loop 1000 times (I know we should avoid loops in R, but here I have to loop).

If I leave the computer to loop, the amount of memory R takes up increases a lot, so much so that my Mac crashes. However, if I break the loop then the memory 'clears up'. So basically if I break the loop manually after 50 iterations and then just continue it from there and continue to do so 200 times, it works 100%. What I also noticed, is that RStudio takes up A LOT of memory, whereas the rsession takes less (although both reduce if I do this manual breaking of the loop).

Any ideas/help on this problem?

I tried using gc() at the end of each loop, but it does not help.

Comment: Give an example of your code, some data to work on and the expected output. There may be an alternative solution to the problem.Without seeing the problem, it's hard to say.

Comment: Hard to tell the cause, but you could keep the output in a file with append, rather than (I am guessing) growing the object inside the loop. Please provide example code forloop with data.

Comment: I will try to adjust my code to produce an example... however the object does not grow, it basically fills in an em dataframe, so the dimensions stay the same through the entire loop

Comment: You should never call `gc` manually. It doesn't help, potentially harms, and slows down your code.